# Error: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable in Recommendation System

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I am working on a process for Clothing Recommendation System. Firstly, I got a problem with creating User Profiles.

Does any body know about it

```
  def get_item_profile(item_id):
        idx = item_ids.index(item_id)
        item_profile = tfidf_matrix[idx:idx+1]
        return item_profile
    
    def get_item_profiles(ids):
        item_profiles_list = [get_item_profile(x) for x in ids]
        item_profiles = scipy.sparse.vstack(item_profiles_list)
        return item_profiles
    
    def build_users_profile(person_id, interactions_indexed_df):
        interactions_person_df = interactions_indexed_df.loc[person_id]
        user_item_profiles = get_item_profiles(interactions_person_df['contentId'])
        
        user_item_strengths = np.array(interactions_person_df['eventStrength']).reshape(-1,1)
        #Weighted average of item profiles by the interactions strength
        user_item_strengths_weighted_avg = np.sum(user_item_profiles.multiply(user_item_strengths), axis=0) / np.sum(user_item_strengths)
        user_profile_norm = sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(user_item_strengths_weighted_avg)
        return user_profile_norm
    
    def build_users_profiles(): 
        interactions_indexed_df = interactions_train_df[interactions_train_df['contentId'] \
                                            .isin(user_df['contentId'])].set_index('personId')
        user_profiles = {}
        for person_id in interactions_indexed_df.index.unique():
            user_profiles[person_id] = build_users_profile(person_id, interactions_indexed_df)
        return user_profiles
```

It showed the ERROR when I run this code.

```
user_profiles = build_users_profiles()
len(user_profiles)
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-e5f681f1b3bb> in <module>()
----> 1 user_profiles = build_users_profiles()
      2 len(user_profiles)

2 frames
<ipython-input-23-0f847c74d142> in get_item_profiles(ids)
      5 
      6 def get_item_profiles(ids):
----> 7     item_profiles_list = [get_item_profile(x) for x in ids]
      8     item_profiles = scipy.sparse.vstack(item_profiles_list)
      9     return item_profiles

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: it's really hard to reproduce what you're seeing here... actually impossible because your build_users_profiles() function refers to dataframes that we can't see. But that aside, it seems like you need to answer the question "Why is the variable `ids` of the type `numpy.int64` rather than an iterable, which I was expecting?" I would start by trying this change inside of `build_users_profile`: `get_item_profiles( interactions_person_df['contentId'].tolist() )`. Ensure that you're passing an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `user_item_profiles = get_item_profiles(interactions_person_df['contentId'])` in `build_users_profiles()` function, as I may guess, you pass a specific user profile, which I suppose is of `numpy.int64` type.
2. Then in `item_profiles_list = [get_item_profile(x) for x in ids]` in the `get_item_profiles(ids)` function you try to iterate on it, which results in the upper mentioned error.

Cheers.

Comment: so next error is " TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable "

Comment: yes, because you try to iterate the `int` which does not have the methods that iterable objects have.